# How to make web.config parametrized in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, web-config

## First of all

I want to separate my ***web.config*** file and any sensitive data by separating into 2 different files.

## Something like

1. web.config
2. sensitiveData.config

## Moreover

I need to this to be configuration dependent. This can be implemented by xml-transform. But I don't know how to make web.config parametrised and configuration dependent.

## How I tried

My idea is to add keys into ***appSettings*** and use in web.config, additionally here is a property ***appSettings.File*** where can be stored file with params and in xml-transformations I can simply change file to change configuration.
Well, I know about appSettings, I have added some

```xml
</appSettings>
    <add key="MyConnstring" value="connstring" />
</appSettings>
```

But it is a mistake, because this can't be done, this is incorrect

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="sqlwork" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" connectionString=MyConnstring />
</connectionStrings>
```

## To summarise

Is there any ideas how it can be done to perform.

1. Sensitive data in a separate file
2. Configuration dependent sensitive data

Answer (score 0):

its possible to move connection strings and other sensitive data in appsettings.

```
<configuration...
  <appSettings configSource="config/appSettings.config"/>
  <connectionStrings configSource="config/connections.config"/>   
  ....
```

Here, `appSettings.config` in config folder contains sensitive app settings and `connections.config` contains the connection strings.

Reference: [How can I simplify my Web.config file?](https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/the-asp-net-2-0-anthology-101-essential-tips-tricks-hacks/preview/how-can-i-simplify-my-web-config-file-a64852b)

You can still read the settings and connection strings using `ConfigurationManager`.